# In parabola why the angle at focus is $90$

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

The green line below is tangent drawn at point $P$. This construction uses the fact that the angle $PFT$ is $90$ degrees. But it doesn't give any explanation of why it must be $90$. Is there any simple way to see this with or without calculus?

Intuitively, when $P$ are right above $F$, it is clear that the angle is 90 because $PF$ is vertical and $FT$ is horizontal. As $P$ moves to the right, it seems $T$ also moves upkeep the angle at focus $90$. I'm not that sure how to approach proving things like these... Help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Video on above construction is [here](https://youtu.be/MIkIWEAE2RY?t=289) . (Watching this video is not needed to answer my question. I think I've included all the necessary details in the question itself)

Comment: I would look for similar or even congruent triangles. If $Q$ is the foot of the altitude from the directrix to $P$, then $PQ=PF$ and the tangent line bisects $\angle{FPQ}$.

Comment: Ok.. In triangles $PFT$ and $PQT$ we have $\angle PQT=90$,  $PQ = PF$ and $PT=PT$. How do we know the tangent bisects $\angle FPQ$ ? @amd

Comment: The reflective property.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an image that can help you visualize the reflective property (incoming horizontal rays are reflected toward the focus) and why the tangent bisects $\angle FPQ$.

[image: Tangent in P bisects angle FPQ]

Comment: Ah, if we assume that the parabola reflects the incoming horizontal rays through the focus, then by angle of incidence = angle of reflection, the tangent indeed bisects $\angle FPQ$. Thank you  :) the graph really helped :)  I'll google a bit why the horizontal rays have to go through the focus. Thanks again :)